# Sobreposição de itens no ListView

Tags: c#, android

Bom dia!

Tenho uma aplicação **android** implementada em **c#**. Esta aplicação exibe um "list view" com os produtos. Cada produto possui informações que podem ser visualizadas ao clicar no botão "V" e ocultadas ao cliente no botão "/\".
As informações são exibidas/ocultadas normalmente quando o "list view" tem mais de 1 item. Porém, sempre que o "list view" tem apenas 1 item, ocorre a seguinte situação:

Clico em "V" para exibir as informações:

Clico em "/\" para ocultar as informações:

Ao acionar o botão "/\", o "list view" deveria voltar ao estado original da lista com 1 item. Porém está ocorrendo essa "sobreposição" de informações.

Como garantir que essa "sobreposição" não aconteça?

Observações importantes:

- Esse problema só ocorre quando o list view tem apenas 1 item.
- O problema não ocorre sempre, ou seja, mesmo com o list view exibindo
  1 item, algumas vezes as informações são ocultadas corretamente.

Desde já, obrigada.

Comment: Este comportamento me parece muito o comportamento do ExpandableListView, que é um componente existente do Android, onde você extende BaseExpandableListAdapter e ele ja trata esse abrir/fechar. Achei um video explicando em Xamarin mesmo como fazer, veja se te dá uma luz: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9k1zVNVMauo

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática vou olhar o vídeo. Obrigada.

Comment: Pode postar o arquivo com o layout do item da ListView e o código completo do Adapter?

Comment: @MárcioOliveira layout acrescentado na descrição da pergunta.

Comment: O seu layout está com uma hierarquia de views bem complexa. Dificil de avaliar só olhando pela página aqui (teria que copiar e colar num projeto do Android Studio). Por que você não tenta usar o ContraintLayout? Dá prá fazer tudo que você fez sem precisar de nenhum LinearLayout (talvez só o que você quer ocultar). Não sei se vai resolver o problema, mas com certeza vai deixar o layout muito mais limpo e performático (muitos LinearLayout aninhados não é uma boa, especialmente com weight). Vou dar uma olhada com calma mais tarde no PC. Se puder, posta o Adapter completo também.